# homeomorphism between maninifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Exist a local homeomorphism between the manifolds with boundary $[0,1) \times [0,1) $ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$? I don't think that a local homeomorphism like this can exist..

Comment: In fact, it exists a global homeomorphism between these manifolds. To see that, you can check first that $[0,1)$ and $\mathbb R_+$ are homeomorphic using $\tan$ function.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ ? It depends on whether $\mathbb{R}_+$ includes $0$ or not, it seems. So specifically, is it $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$ (which has a boundary), or on the other hand is it $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$ which has no boundary? [note it's a common notation for $\mathbb{R}_+$ to mean the positive reals, rather than the nonnegative reals.]

Comment: In my definition $\mathbb{R}^n_+=\{(x_1,\dots , x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon x_n \ge 0 \} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An initial map from $[0,1)\times [0,1)$ to a quarter circle can be done by taking $(x,y)$ and dividing by the length $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Now a map from the quarter circle to a semicircle can be defined by the complex map $f(z)=z^2.$ At this point you have arrived at a half-disc, in which the points on the bounding semicircle of radius 1 are not in the half-disc (except that  the points of $(-1,1) \times \{0\}$ are in the half-disc). Finally apply the radial map sending $r$ to $r/(1-r)$ to expand the half disk to cover the upper half-plane (including the $x$ axis).

Answer (score 0):

> **hint**
>   $$r\exp(i(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)):[0,1)\times[0,1)\rightarrow\text{half disk}$$

I think then you can easily make a half disk into $\mathbb H$.

> Attention: $\mathbb R^2_{+}$ is without boundary; $\mathbb H$ is half plane.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. In the lectures that I follow, $\mathbb{R}^{2}_+$ has boundary. By definition $\partial \mathbb{R}^{n}_+=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.Than you say me that exist a local homeomorphism?

Comment: @andreasvr I'm sorry and I confuse $\mathbb R^2_{+}$ with $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x>0,y>0\}$. And do you mean that $\mathbb R^2_{+}$ is half plane $\mathbb H$.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand your example. How is define that function that you have written?

Comment: @andreasvr I want to let every point rotate $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to make a $[0,1)\times[0,1)$ into a half disk. But there is something wrong in my expression above. I'm fixing it.